# Facebook login in react-native & firebase 3.1

Tags: facebook, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Recently firebase team have released their new version 3.1 of firebase which is compatible with react-native. I'm trying to use the new firebase api with facebook.

Since firebase doesn't support popup or redirect in react-native, i'm using [react-native-fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) to get the access token but when I'm trying to use auth.signInWithCredential, the sign in fail on

> code: "auth/app-not-authorized",
>   message: "This app, identified by
>   the domain where it's hosted, is not authorized to use Firebase
>   Authentication with the provided API key. Review your key
>   configuration in the Google API console."

This is my code. any help would be very much appreciated.

```
import { LoginManager, AccessToken} from 'react-native-fbsdk';
import firebase from '../Services/firebase';

const auth = firebase.auth();
const provider = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;

LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile'])
.then(loginResult => {
    if (loginResult.isCancelled) {
        console.log('user canceled');
        return;
    }
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
    .then(accessTokenData => {
        const credential = provider.credential(accessTokenData.accessToken);
        return auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    })
    .then(credData => {
        console.log(credData);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We managed to find the problem. It seems that the credentials firebase gave us were obsolete for some reason.
From google [console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) we found out, a new apiKey was somehow generated (maybe during the upgrade to firebase 3?) and the firebase key was marked as Previous key.
Once we updated the new apiKey in our application, everything started working.

Comment: Do you have a full working example of this? I would love to see it.. I am struggling..

Comment: are you sure you're getting the same error as I do? are u sure you updated the keys according to the credentials in the google console?

Comment: Yeah Credentials are all updated.. does this current code work for you?

Comment: yes. you might not have published the app in facebook, or you are using permissions not reviewed by facebook? If you do, then only certain roles will be able to login. other people won't.

Comment: anyway you could send me the source to your code (just the facebook login).. would love to see it.

Comment: The code in the example is the entire Facebook login process. I'm not at liberty to expose our entire source code.

Comment: What kind of API Key you've created? "Browser Key"? If so which referrers we should use there?

Comment: We access firebase from iPhone, android,web & server, so we have 4 keys one of each type.

Comment: @JoeCaraccio A bit late, but I created a facebook/firebase example project  here: https://github.com/J-Priebe/react-native-facebook-firebase